# Custom aggregate function on summarize

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to calculate a statistic mode on a column during summarization of a table.

My `CalculateMode` function that I try is like this:

```
.create function CalculateMode(Action:int, Asset:string, Start:long, End:long) {
Event
    | where Time between (Start .. End) and IdAction == Action and IdDevice == Device
    | summarize Count = countif(isnotnull(Result) and isnotempty(Result)) by tostring(Result)
    | top 1 by Count desc
    | project ActionResult
}
```

OR

```
.create function CalculateMode(T:(data:dynamic)) {
T
    | summarize Count = countif(isnotnull(data) and isnotempty(data)) by tostring(data)
    | top 1 by Count desc
    | project data
}
```

when i using first coding on summarizing:

```
Event
    | summarize Result = CalculateMode(toint(IdAction), tostring(IdDevice), Start, End) by Category
```

Obtain this error *No tabular expression statement found* and
when i using second coding on summarizing:

```
Event
    | summarize Result = CalculateMode(Result) by Category
```

I get this error

> CalculateMode(): argument #1 must be a tabular expression

What can I do? Where am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't just do `summarize Result = CalculateMode(Result)`. You have to decide which aggregation function you want to `summarize` by (see the full list of aggregation functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator#list-of-aggregation-functions)).

Comment: How to calculate statistic mode during aggregation?

Comment: Please elaborate the question.

Comment: I want calculate statistic mode of Result for every Category. How to?

Comment: I don't understand. Please update the question, and provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: How to calculate a statistic mode during summarize aggregation?  `Event | summarize Result = Mode(Result) by Category`

Comment: Again, I don't understand your question. Please update the question, and provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: I have a column with this values [Apple, Orange, Orange]; the statistic mode is Orange (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)). How calculate this on Kusto?

Comment: Again, I can't help you if you don't provide sample input and expected output. There's no point in continuing the discussion in comments, until you update the question. Or better, delete this one, and create a new one, with all the information.